# Use of Country/Region during FCM project creation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

While creating FCM Project in my FCM account console, I could see that we have to select country/region. What is the use of the region? I searched a lot, but couldn't find what is the role of it. I understand that FCM is allowed to be used only in certain countries just like playstore account and publishing the app. I would like to know whether there are implications of selecting the country/region in sending notification to a person exists in other country apart from the country that I have selected.

Comment: Its just to set appropriate currency for your revenue reporting.  Notification can be sent to any part of the world including the country you had selected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the information tip pretty much explains this.

> This represents the country/region of your organization/company. Your selection also sets the appropriate currency for your revenue reporting. The selected country does not determine the location of your data for Firebase features. Google may process and store Customer Data anywhere Google or its agents maintain facilities.

Screenshot:

[image]